# Find/Search and Delete in Dimensional Array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, multidimensional-array

I have been having this little problem with locating/finding and deleting an object in a dimensional array.

The array I am dealing with is this:

```
array:2 [▼
    0 => array:1 [▼
       "subject" => array:2 [▼
           "name" => "history"
           "level" => "hl"
    ]
]
    1 => array:1 [▼
        "subject" => array:2 [▼
            "name" => "french"
            "level" => "hl"
        ]
    ]
]
```

This contains a subject object with the name of the subject and the level. Firstly I am having trouble locating the subject with a name. I have tried this to no avail:

```
$test = array_search('history', $user_subjects);
```

I am guessing that I am not targeting a dimensional array correctly.

Also, a user should be able to delete a subject with the subject name. For example, if the user specifies 'history' I would like to remove the object to do with history:

```
{
    "subject": {
        "name": "history",
        "level": "hl"
    }
},
```

Is there anyway to locate a subject using its name and deleting the object that contains that name?

*EDIT:*
I get the array from my database:

```
//Get the users' chosen subject to delete
$input = $subject;

//Laravel User Model
$user = Auth::user();

//Get the user subject array
$user_subjects = $user->subjects;
```

Comment: Since you have tagged this question laravel I was wondering if you are using a query builder to get this information, could you add some info as too how you retrieve the arrays?

Comment: This is JSON, not a Php array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php

$json =<<<JSON
[
{
    "subject": {
        "name": "history",
        "level": "hl"
    }
},
{
    "subject": {
        "name": "french",
        "level": "hl"
    }
}
]
JSON;

$data = json_decode($json, TRUE);

foreach($data as $key => $value)
    if($value['subject']['name'] == 'history')
        unset($data[$key]);

var_export($data);
```

Output:

```
array (
  1 => 
  array (
    'subject' => 
    array (
      'name' => 'french',
      'level' => 'hl',
    ),
  ),
)
```

And back to JSON if needed:

```
$json = json_encode(array_values($data), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```